# APNS APPLE C# sslstream response

Tags: c#, iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

i want to use APNS from Apple with a c# service. The service runs perfect.
What i wanna have is the feedback from Apple if have send the pans to apple.
So what i need is the feedback from a sslstream.

Can anybody help me and tell me how i gat a feedback from the server within the sslstream ?

Thanks in advance

Here is my code how i send sthe pans to the apple server :

```
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, APNS_PORT);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(),
        false,
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
        null
        );

     sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, true);

     sslStream.Write(array);
     sslStream.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

From this apple link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

> If you send a notification and APNs finds the notification malformed
>   or otherwise unintelligible, it returns an error-response packet prior
>   to disconnecting. (If there is no error, APNs doesn’t return
>   anything.) Figure 5-3 depicts the format of the error-response
>   packet.

I assume you just read back from the stream, however I haven't gotten this working yet myself.
I've attempted sending malformed requests in an effort to reponse packet, however my read call gets blocked, seemingly waiting for the ANPS to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I got these code from [APNS Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp).

```
        if (!this.apnsStream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated)
        {
            if (this.Error != null)
            {
                this.Error(this, new NotificationException(4, "Ssl Stream Failed to Authenticate"));
            }
        }

        if (!this.apnsStream.CanWrite)
        {
            if (this.Error != null)
            {
                this.Error(this, new NotificationException(5, "Ssl Stream is not Writable"));
            }
        }
```

Where **apnsStream** is like you **sslStream**. I believe that those events could be the feedback that you are searching.